# OAuth API with and without user context

Tags: api, rest, authentication, architecture, oauth

I'm about to code up a new RESTful API, in the design phase. Several folks I've talked to keep telling me about OAuth so I'm doing some homework.

One thing I don't really see out there, and maybe not many (no one?) is doing it, but I'd like this API I'm working on to function with or without the context of a user.

Basically, if you call the API with an authenticated user, some parameters are loaded from the user's preferences. But I'd like to structure it such that the same calls can be invoked without a user in which case they require additional parameters that would have been read from a user account.

Would this be cumbersome to implement, being that I'd like to use OAuth for the authentication component of the user-based method signatures? Would it be better to just build them as two separate APIs?

Another goal I have is to use the same *application key*/*application secret* paradigm for both scenarios, if possible.

Just so you have a more concrete idea what I mean, imagine these to psuedo function signatures I'd like to support in my API

```
/**
 * Search, when called with a user. Here I'd like to authenticate via OAuth
 */
function search(string search, object user)

/**
 * Search, when called without a user requires more arguments.
 * These calls require application key/application secret
 * but no user authentication.
 */
function search(string search, object coupon_preferences, object store_preferences)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth 2.0 (RFC 6749) defines the flow as **Client Credentials Grant**.

In the flow, a client application accesses the token endpoint and OAuth authorization server issues an access token to the client without any user authentication/authorization.

See "[4.4 Client Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4)" of RFC 6749 for details.

Comment: Right, so basically being able to support calls without authentication/authorization is a component of OAuth. Appreciate this.